# Hidden products on Big Cartel

Tags: product, hidden, bigcartel

I'm trying to have a hidden product on my Big Cartel store. I'd like it only to be available via a direct link, and not appear anywhere else. Thanks in advance for any help!

I tried selecting the hidden option but that just makes the direct link not work.